# Add a newline in Makefile 'foreach' loop

Tags: makefile

Is it possible to insert a new-line to be executed within a `foreach` loop in a Makefile?

Currently, I have the following:

```
$(foreach my_lib,$(MY_LIBS),$(call my_func,results,boxer,$(my_lib)))
```

Now, assuming that I have:

```
MY_LIBS = lib1 \
          lib2
```

The above `foreach` loop would evaluate to:

```
lib1 lib2
```

I would like this to evaluate to:

```
lib1
lib2
```

Is it possible to insert a newline in the `foreach` loop to accomplish this?

Thank you.

Comment: Silly Q time: why do you need the newline?

Comment: In my actual Makefile, "m_func" expands "lib1" and "lib2" into "make ... lib" commands.  Thus, if the line gets evaluated as "make ... lib1 make ... lib2," then the execution fails.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
define \n


endef

$(error Here is a message${\n}with embedded${\n}newlines.${\n}${\n}hooray!)
```

You can use `${\n}` in things like `$(subst...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by using

```
define MY_LIBS
lib1
lib2
endef
```

In more complex cases, where you want to generate multiline makefile commands from the loop, you will need to use the `eval` function.

Comment: Unfortunately, the MY_LIBS macro is defined across multiple Makefiles that are included in a root Makefile.  We add to the MY_LIBS macro with "+=" in the included Makefiles.  Thus, I don't think the "define" and "endef" would work for me.  I can look more into how to use "eval" to solve this problem.