# Multiple files as arguments to make. Is my approach ok?

Tags: unix, gcc, makefile

I'm trying to create a universal makefile for my lab problems. There are five tasks, and each one requires separate C file compiled and ran. As I have to include some additional libraries while using gcc I'd like to just type `make ZAD=first second` and have first.c and second.c compiled. The problem is I don't know how to iterate properly through the `ZAD` list in the makefile. I can separate the tasks in `for` loop, but I can't force a newline char in this loop. This example will explain better (the following is my makefile):

```
ZAD = first second

main: $(foreach dir, $(ZAD), $(dir).o) 
    $(foreach dir, $(ZAD), gcc $(dir).o -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm -o $(dir))
    $(foreach dir, $(ZAD), rm $(dir).o)

first.o: first.c
    gcc -Wall -c first.c

second.o: second.c
    gcc -Wall -c second.c
```

Here's what I get when for instance I try to compile solely second.c:

```
wojtasskorcz@wojtek-laptop:~/mownit/lab1dom$ make ZAD=second
gcc -Wall -c second.c
gcc second.o -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm -o second
rm second.o
```

And everything's fine, but when i try to compile first.c and second.c at one go here's what happens:

```
wojtasskorcz@wojtek-laptop:~/mownit/lab1dom$ make ZAD='first second'
gcc first.o -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm -o first  gcc second.o -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm -o second
gcc: error: gcc: No such file or directory
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

I came to the conclusion, that it's because in the second `foreach` in makefile there's no newline character. But I don't have a clue how to insert it there. Or maybe there's another approach to this problem?

EDIT:
Problem solved by Beta, although here's another way I've found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788276/add-a-newline-in-makefile-foreach-loop)

So my edited makefile looks like this:

```
define \n


endef

ZAD = first second

main: $(foreach dir, $(ZAD), $(dir).o)
    $(foreach dir, $(ZAD), gcc $(dir).o -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm -o $(dir)${\n})
    $(foreach dir, $(ZAD), rm $(dir).o${\n})

%.o: %c
    gcc -Wall -c %.c
```

Everything works as intended now. And once again thanks Beta for your answer.

Comment: What's wrong with using pattern rules??

Comment: I didn't know about them, honestly. Seems a great idea, but I can't see how could I use them for my `main` rule. Of course `first.o` and `second.o` can be easily translated to pattern rules. Can you explain more? Or maybe rewrite my `main` rule?

Comment: Well, what can I say other than: SO works its magic again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
%: %.o
    gcc $^ -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm -o $@

%.o: %.c
    gcc -Wall -c $< -o $@
```

Invoke it by `make -r first second`.

The first rule says "build `something` out of `something.o`". The second says "build `something.o` out of `something.c`". The `-r` in the invocation says "don't use the built-in rules" (since there's a built-in rule for building `something` out of `something.c` which would take precedence over the first rule).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, works like charm! Although it's kinda mysterious to me how it works so i managed to find a way to only slightly edit my code, I've posted it below.