# Trouble printing newline in makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

How can I print a newline in a makefile?

For instance, if I have a target:

```
printIt:
        @echo "Compiling..."
```

How could I print out

`Compiling...`

I had read somewhere that you can define one.
But I have tried what is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788276/add-a-newline-in-makefile-foreach-loop):

```
define \n

endef



printit:
        @echo "${\n}Compiling..."
```

But this doesn't print the newline. I have also tried a c++ style "\n". 
I'm using `GNU Make 3.81`.

Comment: You need two blank lines in the definition of `\n`

Comment: That won't work as used in your recipe. _make_ first expands the entire recipe, and then passes each line in the result to a separate shell invocation. The first command will therefore be `echo "`, which is a syntax error

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use:

```
@echo ""; echo "Compiling..."
```

The first `echo` echoes a newline; the second echoes the message.

Answer (score 2):

In some implementations of `echo` eg. Bash, you can use `echo -e` to interpret escape characters. Use

```
printIt:
        @echo -e "\nCompiling..."
```

Comment: You can usually use the POSIX [`printf`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html)
command (not the function) reliably: `printf '\nCompiling...\n'` — and that doesn't depend on the vagaries of which shell is in use.  It doesn't print newlines unless you request them.