# Insert a new-line in a Makefile $(foreach ) loop

Tags: makefile, newline

I'm compiling a large list of files in a Makefile.

```
my.list : ${deps}
    rm -f $@
    $(foreach F,$^,echo "${F}" >> $@;)
```

but ${deps} can be large and the generated command-line could be too large for one SHELL call. Is it possible to replace `';'` by a newline '\n' ?

Comment: I'm assuming your real target is more complicated than `echo` in the loop? Because there's no reason to use `foreach` for this example at all. You can just `echo $^` directly.

Comment: @EtanReisner, won't that put everything on a single line?

Comment: @JonathanWakely Ah, true, `printf '%s\n' then.

Comment: @EtanReisner yes, it's complicated: I'm generating a Makefile on the fly and I've got more than 10000 files in deps.

Comment: updated: changed title to CR->newline

Comment: Then maybe doing it in Make isn't the right approach. N.B. you still say "carriage-return" in the question and tags.

Comment: Are you actually hitting command-line length limits? Or is this theoretical? Is the limiting factor the length of `DEPS` contents or the repeated command string? Have you thought about not using a single target for this and instead having individual targets per-dep (and then possibly one `my.list` target that `cat`s the individual files together)?

Comment: "Are you actually hitting command-line length limits?" no currently, but my number of ${deps} could be large (>10000).

Comment: OK, I've solved the problem by putting the content of ${deps} in the memory of my Makefile-generator. I'd prefer a pure-makefile solution though.

Comment: example usage: https://gist.github.com/lindenb/0bbb814a62ab68f47ca0

Comment: As Etan Reisner says, you need to figure out which is lower, the maximum length of the content of a `make` variable or the maximum length of a `bash` command line. This may depend on the versions used.

Comment: An alternative approach is to split the rules: generate one rule per, say, 1000 `${deps}` elements, and another rule to combine the results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a newline in Makefile 'foreach' loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4788276/add-a-newline-in-makefile-foreach-loop)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As already mentioned in Jonathan Wakely's answer, the straightforward answer is

```
define newline


endef
```

Interestingly enough, for all chars except newline there is an easier way to get non-printable characters into variables with some help from the shell, e.g.:

```
tab := $(shell printf '\011')
```

It won't work here, though, because the builtin shell function replaces all newlines by spaces.

The version above is still a bit fragile though, in particular when combining with automake which will silently remove the second consecutive newline from the input file, turning `newline` into an empty variable. To force it to keep the newline, we can extend the snippet:

```
blank :=
define newline

$(blank)
endef
```

Finally, to actually get a separate shell command for each dependency, you need to run the generated string through `eval`:

```
define generate-rule =
my.list : $(1)
    rm -f $$@
    $(foreach F,$$^,$(newline)$(tab)echo "${F}" >> $@)

endef

$(eval $(call generate-rule,$(deps)))
```

Answer (score 8):

You can define a variable that expands to a newline like so:

```
define NEWLINE

endef
```

Now you can use `$(NEWLINE)` to expand to a newline.

This won't change anything though, the `foreach` will still generate a single command with embedded newlines between the statements, rather than a single command with `;` between the statements.

Comment: Will this work in a recipe to create multiple lines that run as multiple shell commands?

Comment: I don't know, but then I'm not sure the problem the OP is worried about is a real concern anyway.

Comment: It depends on what the real target is instead of `echo` if it is a large command line and the list in `DEPS` really is **huge** it might be possible to exceed the length limits of a single command line this way.

Comment: On GNU/Linux using Bash the command line can be unlimited, so it might not be a real problem. On other platforms it will be.

Comment: This is, ironically, missing a newline ;)

Answer (score 3):

Possibly the most straight-forward answer is to use:

```
@printf "\n"
```

You can also use this, as I commonly do, to show a description when each new make target executes.  An example target:

```
.PHONY: clean-version
clean-version:    ## Reset version back to committed version number
    @printf "\n## Reset version to last committed version number ##\n\n"; \
    $(GIT) checkout $(VERSION_FILE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing ';' by a carriage-return will produce a string of the same size, subject to the same problem.

"foreach" is simply a string expansion. If you want to execute a separate command for each item, you can use a for loop.

```
my.list : ${deps}
    rm -f $@
    (for F in $^; do echo $$F >> $@ ; done)
```

Comment: Why use () to start a subshell? This will still create a single shell command that includes the whole list of `deps`, although at least it won't repeat the command for every item

Comment: see Etan Reisner's  comment "if it is a large command line and the list in DEPS really is huge it might be possible to exceed the length limits of a single command line this way"

Comment: This helps (barring the sub-shell bit) if the command is the limiting factor and not the contents of `DEPS` itself.

Comment: Well, I tried the command
    echo $(seq 1000000)
which first expands to a one million word command, and executes without a problem (bash 4.2.37)
Are Makefile variables subject to the same limitations ?
Same for
   L=$(seq 1000000)
   echo $L
so, is there a real limitation ?

Comment: The `ARG_MAX` limit applies to how long a command line you can pass from one process to another, but if the shell evaluates the arguments internally, this particular limitation does not affect that.

Answer (score 0):

Edit -- after some revisions, it looks like the only problem with my original was not due to the whitespaces, but with `MAKE_O`. I've fixed it in my version, but I'll mostly be removing them below.

By the way the original post was written, I'm not sure if my solution will be relevant. However, I found myself in the middle of a `define` already inside a `foreach`, and couldn't figure out how to insert a newline using any of the other answers as given.

Solution:

```
define BR
$(1)

endef

define MAKE_O
$(1): $(wildcard $(1:obj/%.o=src/%.cpp)); \
        $(CXX) ... -c $$< \$(call BR)-o $1 ... \
                \$(call BR)&& touch $$@
endef
$(foreach N,main.o,$(eval $(call MAKE_O,$(N))))
```

Desired output (compilation is truncated from [auto-dependency generation](http://make.mad-scientist.net/constructed-include-files/), hence the `touch`):

```
> make obj/main.o
g++ ... -c src/main.cpp \
-o obj/main.o ... \
&& touch obj/main.o
```

I changed `BR` to perform the indentation but leave the end of the line up to you:

```
define BR
$(1)
$(1:%= )        #<remove this comment
endef
define MAKE_O
$(1): $(wildcard $(1:obj/%.o=src/%.cpp)); \
        $(CXX) ... -c $$< $(call BR,\)-o $1 ... \
                $(call BR,\)&& touch $$@
endef
$(foreach N,main.o,$(eval $(call MAKE_O,$(N))))
```

The markup won't help to show this, but line 2 of `BR` is `$(1:%=_space_)_tab_` (the comment itself is not allowed.) Result:

```
> make -n obj/main.o
g++ obj/main.o -c \
        -o obj/main.o && \
        echo statement on new line
```

I used `$(call BR,\)` so that the newline was not parsed as an escape of the new line, and `$(1:%=`*space*`)`*tab* so that the tab is forced (many similar rules have been defined, like `SPACE:=$(SPACE) $(SPACE)` without a prior value.) The variable left of the whitespace must evaluate to *something*. To be clear, removing the whitespace before and after the call: `...lastword$(call BR,\)firstword...` yields `...lastword\n\tfirstword...`, or written out,

```
[^]...lastword \[$]
[^]$(call BR,\)firstword...[$]
```

...yields...

```
[^]...lastword \[$]
[^]        firstword...[$]
```

to achieve the same (using ^,$ to denote the beginning and end of the line. Someone else will probably know how to format/annotate this better.)

My syntax highlighter is decidedly unimpressed with the 'escaped' parentheses and trailing whitespace, but the result is decent.